# Generic method returning a specific object class

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I want to make a webrequest that returns me a JSON. Depend on the URL that I introduce in the argument, the structure of this json is different. then i deserializaobject and I assign this data to a specific object. My question is:

If i want to create a method that returns me an object depending on that URL, what type of argument I have to define?

For example:

```
public objectdependsofURL RequestWeb(string URL)
{
    objectdependsofURL data = new objectdependsofURL();
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(URL);

    using (HttpWebResponse Response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
    using (Stream stream = Response.GetResponseStream())
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
    {
        var json = reader.ReadToEnd();
        data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<objectdependsofURL>(json);
    }

    return data;
}
```

the main idea is not defining one method for every URL, I created it previously. 
I hope the question is clear. I tried this with a class object but maybe this is not the answer.
when I generate the URL I know what will be the object that corresponds to it but when creating the method, how could I define this object that depends on the URL?

Comment: To be clear, the code that passes the URL to this method does not also know what Type it will result in?

Comment: Do you mean how to make the method itself generic? ie: `public objectdependsofURL RequestWeb<objectdependsofURL>(string URL) where objectdependsofURL : new()` ?

Comment: Yes, when I generate the url I know what will be the object that corresponds to it but when creating the method, how could I define this object that depends on the url? @Crowcoder

Comment: In that case do as @Igor has mentioned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you have to do is make the method signature generic.

```
public objectdependsofURL RequestWeb<objectdependsofURL>(string URL) where objectdependsofURL : new()
```

You do need to add a constraint that the type has a public parameterless constructor as you are creating an instance in the first line in the method.

---

As a side note and puerly a matter of preference I would change the name of the generic to be cased in pascal case instead of camel.

Answer (score 0):

Some things come into my mind:

1) Like Crowcoder and Igor said, if the calling method knows the result type, you can turn the method into a simple generic method

```
public T RequestWeb<T>(string URL) where T: new()
```

2) If the calling method don't know the result type, you can try adding an base-class to your json-result types with one method like this:

```
abstract class BaseClass 
{
    public T Get<T>(string name)
    {
        // Do appropriate error handling here (wrong name, wrong case, sub-nodes, ...)
        var field = GetType().GetField(name);
        return (T)field.GetValue(this);
    }
}

public class YourConcreteJsonResultType: BaseClass
{
    public int JsonVarName;
}

public BaseClass RequestWeb(string URL)
{
    //...
}

BaseClass x = RequestWeb("someurl.html");
int y = x.Get<int>("JsonVarName");
```

3) If the calling method don't know the result type and you don't want to use the base-class, you could *think* about using `dynamic` data type. That will work, ***but when you're using this method you surely see that this is not the best option*** ;)

```
public dynamic RequestWeb(string URL)
{
    //...
}

var x = RequestWeb("someurl.html");
var y = x.JsonVarName;
```

As far as I know you do not need to create an instance of `objectdependsofURL` type since  `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<objectdependsofURL>(json);` creates its own instance.